# React js Execute function on submit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple search box on my react app. The box should let the user input a phrase, and then execute another `react.js` function when they hit the enter key. I have tried every combination (put box in a form, not in a form, `onSubmit`, etc), but I can't seem to stop the page from "reloading" when the user inputs the information and presses enter.

HTML:

```
<input className="input" placeholder="Type it Here..." type="text" name="key" id="searchgrid" />
```

React JS Code:

```
searchForMatches(){
    var value = document.getElementById("searchgrid").value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

I just need the `searchForMatches()` function to run when the user types the enter key into the search box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** 
Yes, you get the key pressed with `onKeyPress` event in element
Check the snippet

```js
var Comp = React.createClass({
  searchForMatches(e) {
      var value = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)
      this.setState({
        keyPressed: value

      })
    },
    getInitialState() {
      return ({
        keyPressed: ''
      })
    },
    render() {
      return ( < div >
        < label > Last Key Pressed: {
          this.state.keyPressed
        } < /label><br / >
        < input className = "input"
        placeholder = "Type it Here..."
        type = "text"
        name = "key"
        id = "searchgrid"
        onKeyPress = {
          this.searchForMatches
        }
        />
      
     </div >
      )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render( < Comp / > , document.getElementById('foo'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'></div>
```

Check the system events on React JS (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can get just the key that was pressed, and not the entire value of the box?

Comment: Never mind, just read the docs you attached and it solved everything. thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

For Search Options you can do the following :

HTML :

```
<div class="pull-right" style='display:block;'>
                  <span style="color:red"><strong>Search Products</strong></span>
                    <form method="get">

                      <input name="keysearch" value="" placeholder="name" id="keysearch" type="text" class="form-control">
                      <span id="loading"></span>
                    </form>
                  <div id="result"></div>
              </div>
```

SCRIPT USED :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var req = null;
  $('#keysearch').on('keyup', function(){
    var key = $('#keysearch').val();
    if (key && key.length > 0){
      $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
      if (req)
        req.abort();
        req = $.ajax({
        url : 'fetch_records.php',
        type : 'GET',
        cache : false,
        data : {
          keysearch : key,
        },
        success : function(data)
        {
          console.log(data)
          if (data)
          {
            $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
            $("#result").html(data).show();

        $("#result").css('position', 'absolute');

        $("#result").css('z-index', '1');

        // style='display:block; position :absolute; z-index:1'
      }
    }
  });
}
else
{
  $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
  $('#result').css('display', 'none');
}



});
});
</script>
```

PHP fetch-records.php File:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','Name_OF_DB');
if(isset($_GET['keysearch']))
{
    $search = $_GET['keysearch'];
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$search);

    // $data = "SELECT * FROM products ";
     $data = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_title LIKE '%{$search}%' order by product_id ";
    // $query = query ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id = ".$id." ORDER BY product_price DESC");

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$data);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
         while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {



                echo"<a  href='create_a_new_page_brother.php?id={$row['product_id']}&price=0' class='list-group-item'>{$row['product_title']}</a>";

            }
    }

}
?>
```